# Whats a good way to loop backwards in a ring buffer?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a buffer:

```
static const int BUFFER_SIZE = 3; // for example
int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

and I want to loop through it

```
int index = 0;
for( ;; )
{
    buffer[index] = ...;
    index = (index + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE; // index = 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, ...
}
```

But what happens if I want to loop through the buffer backwards?
eg: 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, ...

Right now Im doing this:

```
index  = (index <= 0) ? BUFFER_SIZE - 1 : index  - 1;
```

Is there a better way of doing these operations?

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of your first decision we can write:

```
int idx = 0; 
int i=0;
for (;;) {
      buffer[idx] = ...;
      i =  (i+1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
      idx = (BUFFER_SIZE - i) % BUFFER_SIZE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```cpp
for (int *p = buffer;;) {
  if (p == buffer) p = buffer + BUFFER_SIZE;        

  // these next lines could be combined using the pre-decrement operator
  // at expense of some readability
  p--;
  int index = int(p - buffer); // in case you need the zero-based index
  *p = ...;   
}
```

or this:

```cpp
for (int *p = buffer + BUFFER_SIZE - 1;;p--) {
  int index = int(p - buffer); // in case you need the zero-based index
  *p = ...;
  if (p == buffer) p = buffer + BUFFER_SIZE;        
}
```